# Ionic select is not changing to the correct values on change

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, selectionchanged

I have an `ion-select` where on change, I need to update values in other `ion-select` that is related.

The first `ion-select` is for selecting countries, then according to the specified one, the second `ion-select` will display the related major cities.

The problem that is cities displayed are always the one of the following array: `kuwait_ar` except of the country of Kuwait , where the cities are the correct ones `kuwait_en`.

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-h5nq3w).

Here is the code for `(ionChange)`:

```
displayCities()
  {
    let country = this.formGroup.controls.country.value;
    this.cityArray = [];
    //console.log(country)
    this.cityArray = ((country == "Bahrain" || country == "البحرين") && this.lang=="en")?this.bahrain_cities_en:this.bahrain_cities_ar;
    this.cityArray = ((country == "Oman" || country == "عمان") && this.lang=="en")?this.oman_cities_en:this.oman_cities_ar;
    this.cityArray = ((country == "Qatar" || country == "قطر") && this.lang=="en")?this.qatar_cities_en:this.qatar_cities_ar;
    this.cityArray = ((country == "Saudi Arabia" || country == "المملكة العربية السعودية") && this.lang=="en")?this.ksa_cities_en:this.ksa_cities_ar;
    this.cityArray = ((country == "UAE" || country == "الامارات العربية المتحدة") && this.lang=="en")?this.uae_cities_en:this.uae_cities_ar;
    this.cityArray = ((country == "Kuwait" || country == "الكويت") && this.lang=="en")?this.kuwait_cities_en:this.kuwait_cities_ar;
    //console.log(this.cityArray)

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is happening because you are assigning `this.cityArray` multiple times.  The reason "Kuwait" works correctly, is because it is the last one in the list.

Consider when you select "Bahrain":

```
#1  this.cityArray = ((country == "Bahrain" || country == "البحرين") && this.lang=="en")?this.bahrain_cities_en:this.bahrain_cities_ar;
#2  this.cityArray = ((country == "Oman" || country == "عمان") && this.lang=="en")?this.oman_cities_en:this.oman_cities_ar;
#3  this.cityArray = ((country == "Qatar" || country == "قطر") && this.lang=="en")?this.qatar_cities_en:this.qatar_cities_ar;
#4  this.cityArray = ((country == "Saudi Arabia" || country == "المملكة العربية السعودية") && this.lang=="en")?this.ksa_cities_en:this.ksa_cities_ar;
#5  this.cityArray = ((country == "UAE" || country == "الامارات العربية المتحدة") && this.lang=="en")?this.uae_cities_en:this.uae_cities_ar;
#6  this.cityArray = ((country == "Kuwait" || country == "الكويت") && this.lang=="en")?this.kuwait_cities_en:this.kuwait_cities_ar;
```

Line #1 correctly sets `this.cityArray = this.bahrain_cities_er` because your condition (`country == "Bahrain"` evaluates to `true` AND `this.lang` is set to "en"... GOOD

But... Line #2, `(country == "Oman" || country == "عمان")` evaluates to `false`, so your are reassigning the value of `this.cityArray` = `this.oman_cities_ar`

The same goes for Line #3-#6, thus the last line assigns it to `this.kuwait_cities_ar` as you have experienced.

Perhaps a `switch` statement would work better when only once case gets executed.

However, your approach is very complicated.  You could structure your definitions of country/city names in a nested array or map, so you can simply "look up" the correct list, rather than "figure it out" based on a selected value.  You could also two separate lists, one for each language, then simply swap them out based on the current language.